# How to make a border at the bottom of my thead section?

Tags: html, css, border

So I have a table with only the outside bordered. This is what I want. However, I would also like the bottom of the `<thead>` section to have a border. So basically, there will be a horizontal line between the header row and all the other rows. However, I can't make this happen.

I tried doing something like:

```
thead {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

but this doesn't produce anything. I also tried:

```
th {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: thin; 
}
```

But this leaves very small gaps between each column.
It should look something like this JSFiddle but without the gaps in between (this uses my second code suggestion): http://jsfiddle.net/C8mjK/2/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add this to your table css:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

This will remove the spacing in between the borders of each table cell.

Updated fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/C8mjK/4/